# Filtering the last two years data dynamically based on year SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to filter data based on Marked_Yr dynamically in the View. I cannot use `Created_On` due to bad data and data quality issues.

Every year for Column Marked_YR, From Jan 1st 2019 to May 31st 2019 it will be populated as year `2019` and from June 1st 2019 to May 31st 2020 it will populated as `2020` and the same process repeated.

How can I get Marked_Yr data `2019` and `2020` dynamically without hard coding?

For example:

```
|PersonId|Product|Created_on | Marked_YR | 
+--------+-------+-----------+-----------+
| 1      |P7     |01/01/2018 | 2018      |==> Active record
| 2      |P8     |05/31/2018 | 2018      |==> Active record
| 3      |P2     |06/01/2018 | 2019      |==> Active record
| 4      |P6     |07/01/2018 | 2019      |==> Active record
| 5      |P1     |01/01/2019 | 2019      |==> Active record
| 6      |P2     |02/28/2019 | 2019      |==> Active record
| 7      |P3     |05/31/2019 | 2019      |==> Active record
| 8      |P4     |06/01/2019 | 2020      |==> Active record
| 9      |P4     |12/31/2019 | 2020      |==> Active record
| 10     |P3     |01/01/2020 | 2020      |==> Active record
| 11     |P2     |04/16/2020 | 2020      |==> Active record
| 12     |P4     |06/01/2020 | 2021      | ==> Future record
| 13     |P4     |12/31/2020 | 2021      | ==> Future record
| 14     |P9     |05/31/2021 | 2021      | ==> Future record
| 15     |P7     |06/01/2021 | 2022      | ==> Future record
```

Output in the view:

```
|PersonId|Product|Created_on | Marked_YR | 
+--------+-------+-----------+-----------+
| 3      |P2     |06/01/2018 | 2019      |==> Active record
| 4      |P6     |07/01/2018 | 2019      |==> Active record
| 5      |P1     |01/01/2019 | 2019      |==> Active record
| 6      |P2     |02/28/2019 | 2019      |==> Active record
| 7      |P3     |05/31/2019 | 2019      |==> Active record
| 8      |P4     |06/01/2019 | 2020      |==> Active record
| 9      |P4     |12/31/2019 | 2020      |==> Active record
| 10     |P3     |01/01/2020 | 2020      |==> Active record
| 11     |P2     |04/16/2020 | 2020      |==> Active record
```

Comment: What do you mean "dynamically"?  Are you referring to the current year and last year?

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff. If I checked the view today to May 31st 2019 should have only two Marked_YR's data of 2020 and 2019. And If I checked the view on  June 1st 2019 should have only two Marked_YR's data of 2021 and 2020. Apologize for complicated logic.

Answer (score 0):

in Snowflake

```
WHERE Marked_YR in (YEAR(current_date), YEAR(current_date)-1)
```

or it could be written

```
WHERE Marked_YR BETWEEN YEAR(current_date)-1 AND YEAR(current_date)
```

would also work, and thus also

```
WHERE (Marked_YR = YEAR(current_date)-1 OR Marked_YR = YEAR(current_date))
```

Comment: Hi @simeon. Thanks for your feedback. There is an issue with the logic. For example: If I checked the view on 06-01-2020, The Marked_Yr will be 2021. And the data should populate the records of Marked_Yr of 2021 and 2020 only. Please let me know if more information needed from my side.

Comment: @K.Tom you have a table that has 4 columns, of which 3 seems to be pointless from a fitlering perspective (`PersonId`,`Product`,`Created_on`) and you have some other column `Marked_YR` that want some some range of rows from. Given it's a "year" you can pick years only. you ether want "this year", "next year" or "last year" but that is your problem to decide, I showed you how to get "this year and last year". If you want month level filtering, you are going to need data that can be trusted that has months in it.

Answer (score 0):

Tom, I got your requirement.

Here is my solution, it works in Snowflake, consider **Test2** as your table name

```
select * from Test2
where 
(case when MONTH(current_date) <6  and (marked_yr in (YEAR(current_date) ,YEAR(current_date)-1)) then 1
      when MONTH(current_date) >=6 and (marked_yr in (YEAR(current_date) ,YEAR(current_date)+1)) then 1
     else 0
 end) = 1
```